# Private docker registry and high availability

Tags: registry, docker, mirroring

We are currently running a private registry on one server hosting all our images on it.
If the server crash, we basically loose all our images. We would like to find a way to enable high availability on our images. 
An easy solution I see would be to have a registry instance per server.
A load balancer would redirect(Round robin) the traffic to ones of the registry instances available. Registry instances would share the same network data drive(NFS) to store the images.

Do you see any problems with this solution ?
i.e: If a user push an image on an instance, and another push on another ( Load balancer round robin decision), would it create any lock files on the NFS ?

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Isn't it easier just to back-up and/or mirror the image files?

Comment: It is easier but we don't want any service interruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some [information on this on the docker-registry website](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#high-availability-and-scaling). In short, it seems designed to support multiple registries talking to the same data-store so you shouldn't see any problems.

If reliability is a real issue for you, it might be wise to look at one of the commercial offerings e.g. [enterprise Hub](https://www.docker.com/enterprise/hub/) or the [CoreOS Enterprise Registry](https://coreos.com/products/enterprise-registry/). (Although these seem to stress security and access controls rather than HA).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to back the registry with S3 as described [here](http://romain.dorgueil.net/blog/en/docker/2014/12/21/docker-registry-amazon-s3-storage-backend.html). It's worth running the registry in a container so you can instantly launch another in the event of a catastrophic host/data centre failure. GCloud and OpenStack are also supported by the registry.

If you are concerned with data loss add redundancy to your persistence and ensure regular backups. You should also ensure your builds are idempotent so you can rebuild images if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

registry need to cache some meta data, using inmemory by default. You can change cache configuration to use redis.

https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#cache

example config:

```
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
  cache:
    blobdescriptor: redis
redis:
  addr: redis-server-host:6379
  db: 1
  dialtimeout: 1s
  readtimeout: 1s
  writetimeout: 1s
  pool:
    maxidle: 16
    maxactive: 64
    idletimeout: 300s
```

You should change storage method for s3 or any other global storage. I run two registry for high availability.

Comment: I had setup two EC2 instances running Docker registry using S3 as the storage. Soon after, the next attempts to `docker push`  failed with `blob upload unknown`. I disabled one of the two EC2 instances (to troubleshoot the one) and things instantly started working. That lead me to believe it was something where some data was not being synced/stored in S3. I eventually found this post and it seems this lines up. I'll try with a redis pool but for now I disabled the other node. Thanks for sharing this, saved me a ton of time. Sadly Docker doesn't have a way to store this in S3 today.