# Making the Docker Registry HA

Tags: docker, high-availability, docker-registry

**Please note:** This is a very *similar* question [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540703/private-docker-registry-and-high-availability), but I assert this is *not* a dupe! That other question was clearly based on the (older) Python-based Docker registry, not the latest one that is written in GoLang and seems to be fairly different!

---

I just spent a few hours reading the docs for [setting up a private Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) and have it running on a remote VM with the following characteristics:

- Authenticated using Basic Auth, and I have a test user working with it
- Uses a root CA cert for TLS
- Uses the local file system for storage (I'll probably upgrade this to Ceph/Rados)

So far so good. But now I want to make it HA, and am shocked that the docs don't seem to make any mention of it. In the [*old Python docs*](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#high-availability-and-scaling) there is a whole section devoted to HA, but I'm leery of following them because the newer (GoLang-based) registry doesn't seem to mention HA at all.

So my concerns:

- Is there a way to make the newer (GoLang) registry HA? If so, where are the docs?
- What's the general approach? Cluster registry instances behind a load balancer? Make one the Primary and have 1+ Secondaries? Master/slave?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually referenced in "[Deploying a registry server - Load Balancing Considerations](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/bc010e506e82898178605959056cd3779566e09f/docs/deploying.md#load-balancing-considerations)"

> One may want to use a load balancer to distribute load, terminate TLS or provide high availability. While a full load balancing setup is outside the scope of this document, there are a few considerations that can make the process smoother.
>
> The most important aspect is that a load balanced cluster of registries must share the same resources. For the current version of the registry, this means the following must be the same:
>
> - Storage Driver
> - HTTP Secret
> - Redis Cache (if configured)

That means the actual high-availability feature is considered out-of-scope for the docker distribution project, but it can still be implemented by adding a load balancer.

Comment: Thanks @VonC (+1) - any links regarding the "HTTP Secret" and "Redis Cache"?

Comment: @smeeb the original doc (on the registry V1) came from https://forums.docker.com/t/scaling-out-the-docker-registry/756/2. I don't have much details except the ones presented in a commercial product: http://www.slideshare.net/jelastic/jelastic-451webinar2015